# Двойное экранирование в ответе от контроллера

Tags: java, json, spring, kotlin, экранирование

В контроллер приходит сущность с неразрывным пробелом. Он его дополнительно экранирует.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abc/")
class Controller(
    private val service: service
) {

    @GetMapping("/byId/{id}", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    suspend fun getEntity(
        @PathVariable id: Long,
    ) : EntityResponse {
        val entity = service.getEntity(id)
        println(entity)
        return entity
    }
}
```

В `println` вижу, что неразрывный пробел не экранируется.

Получаю:

```
EntityResponse(statusCode=200, id=2, test=Текст с\u00A0неразрывным пробелом)
```

При этом в insomnia вижу такой ответ:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "id": 2,
  "test": "Текст с\\\u00A0неразрывным пробелом",
}
```

По данному вопросу я находил решения для python, либо для решения проблем в парсинге url. Мне это не подходит.

Прошу помочь в решении.

Answer (score 0):

В JSON сериализации символ неразрывного пробела экранируется, в отличии от println, можно попробовать что-то вроде:

```
@GetMapping("/byId/{id}", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
suspend fun
getEntity(@PathVariable id: Long):
EntityResponse {
    val entity = service.getEntity(id)

    // Заменяем неразрывной пробел на экранированное представление
    entity.test = entity.test.replace('\u00A0', '\\u00A0')

    println(entity)
    return entity
}
```